# Create Procedure to insert values into a table sql

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

I am attempting to create a procedure that will allow me to insert values into a table
the code I have is

```
Create procedure add_instructor 
    @Name char(40), 
    @IAccount char(20)
AS
BEGIN
set nocount on
insert into final_instructors (Name, IAccount) 
values (@name, @IAccount)
end
go;
```

I am getting this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Name char(40), @IAccount char(20)

Comment: There are lots of basic syntax problems: You can't use `@` variables as procedure parameters. Parameters must be in parentheses. Statements must be separated with `;`.

Comment: I suggest you google "mysql stored procedure tutorial"

Comment: If you want to identify parameters, a common pattern in SQL is to prefix with underscore, so `_Name char(4)`, `_IAccount char(20)` etc.

Comment: The AS and GO statements indicate to me that the code is sqlserver not mysql..